# Sitecore media src path wrong?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have just upgraded a Sitecore 6.5 solution to Sitecore 7. It's a very basic site so no major issues.
I ran into one problem though.

A couple of places i want to get the src of an image item in xslt. I do this like so;

```
sc:fld('myImage',.,'src')
```

The output of this is `~/media/folder/myimage.ashx`

But for some reasons this does not work - meaning there is no image displayed. When i copy the src and try to open i directly in a new tab i get redirected to Sitecore login. And there is no security settings on the image.

Then i found out, that when using sc:image for instance, i get another src, which works:
`/sitecore/shell/~/media/folder/myimage.ashx`
But the above does not look right to me?

What is going on and how do i fix it? i have changed nothing in the web.config besides site defnition and datafolder path. Otherwise it is completly stock.

Comment: Try using the Access Viewer in the desktop to review what permissions anonymous has to those media items. Seems like somewhere up the chain it's failing a security check, and Access Viewer will explain why access is denied.

Comment: @KamFigy just double checked the security and everything is ok. There is no restrictions set on the media items, so this is not the problem. The problem, as i see it, is the path to the image, that seems very wrong. At least the working one with sitecore/shell, should not look like that i am guessing?

Comment: When you get the /sitecore/shell path, are you viewing in preview mode?

Answer (score 4):

Prefix the output of sc:fld with a slash '/' so the full path becomes

```
/~/media/folder/myimage.ashx
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use `sc:field` instead of `sc:fld` and you will get friendly url

Answer (score 0):

It is often a point of confusion for folks, so let's go though the way Sitecore is generating and handles media requests. this will give your understanding how it works "under the bonnet" of sc:field().

First of all, check your configuration. MediaLinkPrefix specifies what your media prefix will be at HTML rendered.

```
<setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix" value="~/media/" />
```

On second step as soon as HTML is formed and link contain your desired media prefix within href attribute, your further step will be to set up a handler to handle those links. It can be done at the following configuration setting within         customHandlers node:

```
<handler trigger="~/media/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx" />
```

Finally, you need to associate you handler with exact code that will server your request. Than is configured within httpHandlers node, as below:

```
<add verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="Namespace.ClassName, YourLibrary" />
```

If your MediaPrefix is generating relative links, please make sure the path generated is correct relatively root of your website. Starting relative path with '/'will ensure that.

Hope this explains the mechanism pretty well, however please feel free to ask further question on how it works within a Sitecore.

Cheers!